# How to implement a Delete Observer in Object Box

Tags: java, android, objectbox

I am using `ObjectBox` as storage in my app which data are coming through socket connection and stored directly. An observer with a paginated query is used in `fragment` and applies data changes to `recyclerview`. The problem is how to know if an entry has been deleted from `ObjectBox`, get notified in the `fragment`, and remove it from `recyclerview`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is outlined in the [data observer docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/data-observers-and-rx): you create a `Query` on which you can observe to react to data changes:

```
Query<Task> query = taskBox.query().equal(Task_.complete, false).build();
query.subscribe(subscriptions)
     .on(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
     .observer(data -> updateUi(data));
```

Comment: This approach has already been implemented in my code currently. The problem is how to know which item was deleted and remove it from recyclerview. How should one implement a query for a large number of items and get notified for only removed items? Does it require to get ALL items every time and compare them to recyclerview data and remove one by one?